# Send python web app metrics to InfluxDB

Tags: python, monitoring, metrics, influxdb, statsd

For now I have a such monitoring system configured:

```
web_app (via python statsd client) -> statsd -> ...
    ... -> carbon-relay-ng -> carbon-cache -> whisper
```

And I use `Grafana` over `Graphite` as a graphing tool.

Due to too poor query performance I've decided to change this stack to just `InfluxDB` + `Grafana` bundle. So, my question is how can I send app metrics to the `InfluxDB`? I prefer to keep this bundle pretty simple, so I would like to skip `statsd` if it's possible. Should I replace *python statsd client* with [influxdb-python](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python) and use [telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf) UDP service as an aggregation part in front of the `InfluxDB` or just send metrics directly to the `InfluxDB` instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would send the data to telegraf using the line protocol.

I've used influxdb-python a lot to submit stats directly to InfluxDB. Sending the results locally to telegraf may well be quicker, depending on how quickly and reliably your InfluxDB installation responds - this will block your application if there are delays.

The line protocol seems easier to use to me than the other options, and  telegraf can accept the line protocol directly. A potential downside is that anything you send that way would end up in the database allocated to telegraf stats. Going directly to InfluxDB you can choose which database your data will end up in, although it means bypassing the python module if you'd like to use the line protcol format.

To use influxdb-python and send to InfluxDB directly, you have a choice of JSON format or using a subclass of `SeriesHelper`

### JSON

Creating the JSON structure that the `write_points`/ `write` uses is really awkward and clunky. It only converts it into line format anyway.

Compare the JSON:

```
json_body = [
    {
        "measurement": "cpu_load_short",
        "tags": {
            "host": "server01",
            "region": "us-west"
        },
        "time": "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z",
        "fields": {
            "value": 0.64
        }
    }
]
```

to the line format:

```
# measurement,tag1=tag1value,tag2=tag2value column1=... 
cpu_load_short,host=server01,region=us-west value=0.64 1465290833288375000
```

I know which I think is easier to produce (And I know the timestamps don't match, I'm just using examples). The line format can be `POST`ed straight to InfluxDB using the `requests` library, or sent via UDP if that listener has been configured.

### SeriesHelper

The module has a way to just accept the values and tags, by using [`SeriesHelper`](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python/blob/master/examples/tutorial_serieshelper.py) which can be awkward to set up, but is easy to use.

The example they give is:

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient, SeriesHelper

myclient = InfluxDBClient(host, port, user, password, dbname)

class MySeriesHelper(SeriesHelper):
    # Meta class stores time series helper configuration.
    class Meta:
        client = myclient
        series_name = 'events.stats.{server_name}'
        fields = ['some_stat', 'other_stat']
        tags = ['server_name']
        bulk_size = 5
        autocommit = True


MySeriesHelper(server_name='us.east-1', some_stat=159, other_stat=10)
MySeriesHelper(server_name='us.east-1', some_stat=158, other_stat=20)
```

So you can see from calling MySeriesHelper, that makes life easy once it's set up, but the configuration for the client either needs to be set up in the global scope (which is bad for a module) or in the class definition. This isn't good for getting configuration from a config file or service discovery, so you end up doing things like this in your config parsing functions:

```
# Read host, port, user password, dbname from config file, then:
MySeriesHelper.Meta.client = InfluxDBClient(host, port, user, password, dbname)
# Now it is safe to call MySeriesHelper
```

I've not had issues with reliability with influxdb-python, and most of the time we use `SeriesHelper` classes. It's not the most complex of things, but the idea behind metrics is not that one person with the knowledge adds it all, but that it's part of the way of life of all the people writing code at every part in the chain. From that perspective, ease of use is key to get people to adopt a tool.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! However, I still have two questions. If one use a UDP listener on the InfluxDB side, why you mentioned that sending metrics to the InfluxDB directly would block execution of the app code? And the second one - is InfluxDB optimized to receive a lot of metrics without aggregation in the telegraf on the fly?

Comment: I wrote the part about blocking execution while only thinking of the regular http POST method, apologies for the confusion there. For the second part, the newer database engine in 0.9 onwards (tsm1 I think it's called) should be able to receive a large number of metrics without aggregation. Our first draft of LDAP metrics stored  1 data point per query, about 30 million a day, and InfluxDB coped. (We've aggregated that now just for our own storage size)

Comment: Hm, I'm afraid, that I still have questions. I've started sending my metrics via UDP directly to the InfluxDB instance with `batch-size = 1000` and `batch-timeout = "1s"` settings. However, for now I have only one value per second (I am guessing the last one) stored for unique combination of tags set and fields set. But I want to have exactly all metrics accounted. Looks like I have to switch to the batched metrics sending via HTTP, but I have to somehow eliminate latencies in the app code. Maybe using telegraf can help with it?

Comment: I've not used telegraf to send metrics yet, so I can't help with that, sorry. From the documentation it appears that UDP has 1 second as the lowest resolution, which is awkward.

Comment: Exactly. I'm going to try batched HTTP insertion via some kind of "proxy" agent. Like `statsd` but without any aggregation on the agent side. Only holding incoming metrics for a period and then dump they all at once to the InfluxDB.

Comment: Eventually realised, that there is nothing wrong with 1 second batching due to UDP receiving. An error was in my code. Instead of having `int(round(datetime.utcnow().timestamp() * 1000000000))` it was something like `int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp()) * 1000000000`. So, having only one last value for each second was due to my code. InfluxDB batching works perfectly!

Comment: @IvanVelichko We had to solve 1600 apps only able to send metrics through HTTP, and used Telegraph as such a proxy. You can configure Telegraf to accept InfluxDB format on HTTP with the "http_listener" input plugin, and then have Telegraf bunch it and write to InfluxDB with the UDP output plugin.